# Parsing string of list into list type

Tags: powerquery

I would like to know how to turn the follow:
`"["Apple","Salt","Tree","Song"]"`
into a list a normal list e.g : `["Apple","Salt","Tree","Song"]`

I tried using a variety of methods such as `text.split` but this won't work with lists that are nested.

Comment: Please explain your request better.  How is "["Apple","Salt","Tree","Song"]"  a nested list?

Comment: It is not a nested list, which is correct. The part where i mentioned text.split does not work was to indicate that text.split will not actually turn lists parsed as strings into lists because if you encounter a nested list, it will not work.

Comment: so you want some method that would work on a nested list? If so, please give example of such a list

Comment: Sure, something like this: ```"{{{"2019","2020","2021"},{"2013","2014","2015"}},{{"1999","1996","1980"},{"2003","2004","2005"}}}"```

Comment: is that literally it? Then why not remove the " and } and { characters then split on ,

Comment: Because then you would lose the structure of the nested list and just have a flat list. Ideally you want it to be exactly the same just without it being text and it being a proper list with the different levels nested.